# NULL data becomes 0 on receive

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to retrieve data in a JSON from my backend.

When the data is received from the API, everything works fine. I have several fields with a NULL value, which is expected.

But once I print it out from `console.log`, I found it becomes 0 (integer). And it remains 0 when I assign it to a field.

Like this:

What is from database:

```
{
   key: null
}
```

What is printed and used in React.js

```
{
   key: 0
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who may have encountered a similar issue.

Nothing wrong with React.js. It appears to be a value-fix mechanism triggering the modification of the data received from the backend. Somehow the fix would be applied to previous logs, which caused me to believe the data was modified right after receiving it.

Make sure you are not modifying the data you received directly. That is, don't re-assign values to the json lands to your frontend.